# git push to branch to trigger build

Tags: git, git-push

In the team I am working in, we have automatic builds triggered every time we make a pull request. However this build expires in a set time, before someone can approve the request, thus rendering it unable to be completed. Usually, the way to fix it is to fetch develop and rebase, but what happens when there are no new changes in develop? 
Is there a way to push again to my branch (update the pull request) without making changes?

```
$ git push origin feature/branch -f
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: I just tried to do rebasing and force pushing with develop branch twice where there were no changes on develop branch. There were no two different commits. I think you need to do at least some change in files, at least trivial, in order to be able to do what you want.

Comment: It is a quite large organisation, and they are pretty uptight with code format. I guess one blank line would not be the end of the world. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `git commit --allow-empty -m "Dummy commit to trigger something"; git push`.